# Subtraction for two rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following table named table1 in SQL Server.

```
id  value
1   10
2   100
3   20
4   40
5   50
```

When i execute query following query it gives me  result of 110 which is expected

```
SELECT SUM(value) from table1 where id in (1,2)
```

What i want is opposite of SUM means the output should be 90 or -90.

i know this can be done by writing following query

```
select ((SELECT value from table1 where id in (1)) - (SELECT value from table1 where id in (2)) )
```

but is there any simplified way to do this(something like SUM function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ad16/15) using `Sum()` with `Case`:

```
Declare @SubId int =1

--To get -90 or +90 change the value of @SubId from 1 to 2
Select Sum(Case When Id = @SubId Then value Else -1*Value End) Total
From Table1
Where Id in (1,2);
```

Comment: this is not what i want .. i have done my calculation but this is the closest so i accept this as answer .. thx

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want result to be non-negative or non-positive, you can switch MIN and MAX in the following statement:

```
select max(value) - min(value)
  from table1
 where id in (1,2)
```